# How to fix file conflicts when building rpm package

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to biuld rpm package that requires another package. I want to replace two files form required package and in %post section edit them. But I get an error

```
file /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf from install of puppet-agent-install-5.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-agent-5.0.1-1.el7.x86_64
  file /etc/sysconfig/puppet from install of puppet-agent-install-5.0.1-1.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-agent-5.0.1-1.el7.x86_64
```

My spec file:

```
Name:   puppet-agent-in

#wersja
Version:        5.0.1
Vendor:         01
Summary:        02
Release:        1
License:        Apache License, Version 2.0

Requires(pre):  telnet, puppet-agent >= 5.0

BuildArchitectures:     noarch

BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/BuildRoot

Source1:        cer_pem.crt
Source2:        cer_corpo_pem.crt
Source3:        puppet.conf
Source4:        puppet

Conflicts:      puppet-agent-install < %{version}
Conflicts:      puppet-agent-install > %{version}
Conflicts:      puppet-agent-opl

%description


%install:

%{__install} -d -m 755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/dir_ssl
%{__install} -d -m 755 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/sysconfig

%{__install} -m 644 %{_sourcedir}/cer_corpo_pem.crt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/dir_ssl/cer_corpo_pem.crt
%{__install} -m 644 %{_sourcedir}/cer_pem.crt $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/dir_ssl/cer_pem.crt
%{__install} -m 644 %{_sourcedir}/puppet.conf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
%{__install} -m 644 %{_sourcedir}/puppet $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/sysconfig/puppet


%files

%defattr(-, root, root)
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/dir_ssl/cer_corpo_pem.crt
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/dir_ssl/cer_pem.crt
/etc/sysconfig/puppet
%config /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf

%post
#edit puppet.conf and puppet file
```

Is any possibility to fix this conflict?

Answer (score 2):

## NO

two packages cannot provide the same file. You'll have to find a way around:

- can the configuration be put in a `conf.d` directory?
- don't run puppet with the default configuration. Start puppet yourself and point to your configuration files (on other locations). I have no experience with puppet, but something like: `puppet -c /path/to/your/puppet.conf`

## yes, hacky workaround, not recommended

again: I would not recommend this, but you can hack around by providing `/path/to/your/puppet.conf`, and then mess with the real config files in your `post` sections:

```
%post
mv /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf{,.backup}
ln -s /path/to/your/puppet.conf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf

%postun
if [ $1 == 0 ]; then #uninstall
    # restore file from backup when your package is uninstalled
    mv /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf{.backup,}
fi
```

NOTE: this will work for your installation, but when `puppet` itself is updated; you will lose your configuration file, since it will again be overwritten by /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf from puppet rpm.

Comment: for followers, FWIW, two packages can provide the same directory if it's the same user/permissions (else it's "file conflict" for a directory).